# What is this strange seedling growing in my other plants pot?

Tags: identification, houseplants

This little seedling showed up in my spider plant pot a while ago. Is there any way I could figure out what it is? I moved it to its own pot so that it wouldn’t mess with my spider plant, and it’s still growing.[image]

Comment: It's either a weed or your new favorite plant. That rests with you, not with what it actually is. I get a "weed" *gestalt* from it, but I couldn't tell you what species, so we'll let someone else take a stab at that... But ultimately a weed is in the eye of the beholder as a plant growing where you don't want it. Some are in the written pages of the legislators as "noxious weeds" though, meaning there's a broader and legally binding consensus on where they are not wanted.

Comment: Looks a bit like creeping bellflower, a truly nasty weed, but it's too early to tell. If you want to keep it for awhile, I recommend putting it in its own pot and not in the ground.